# Leaving insignificant variables in a regression - Sources?

Tags: statistical-significance, model-selection, references

I'm aware that this question has been answered many times on this forum, however, I've not seen it accompanied by any sources.

I'm looking for sources which support the inclusion of control variables in a model specification that have economic justification, even if they're insignificant. Since one may expect that not including these variables may result in an omitted variable bias...

Textbooks and journal articles preferred.

Thanks!

A

Comment: If you know they're insiginificant you've already tried them; leaving them out involves variable selection via hypothesis test -- essentially backward elimination, one form of stepwise selection. On those (backward elimination and stepwise as variable selection methods) there's been a number of posts with discussion and references here on site. I usually just point people to chapter 4 of Frank Harrell's *Regression Modeling Strategies*